# Why the Shift+Ctrl+e causing e underlined and start emoji input (linux)?

Tags: linux, emoji, keystroke

Why when i am inside chrome browser for example, when i want to center text using Shift+Ctrl+E key combination it causes appearing e̲ and if i type e̲j̲o̲y̲ and press Enter on keyboard it causes appearing emoji . 
How i can simply fix it?

Comment: Upvote - question accurately described obscure issue that doesn't provide further details.

Comment: I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 21.10, but for me the key combination that caused the underlined 'e' to appear was `Ctrl+.`. This question and the answer helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to check if you have ibus installed. Firstly you should type in terminal:

```
ibus-setup
```

If some window appears you should go to Emoji tab and delete key combination
[image]

||

/

[image]

If you have nothing like ibus-setup available in your terminal go to your home directory

```
cd ~/
```

Look if you have `.profile` file there. If no you can create one if yes open it and add:

```
#My modifications
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
export QT_IM_MODULE="xim"
export XMODIFIERS="@im=xim"
#End of my modifications
```

Save the file and logout and login or reboot your computer. Next time when you will start chrome you will be able to use Shift + Ctrl + E key combination.